# ternary operator does not change backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

i'm trying to set background when input is null and keep this value when have some

```
function emptyto(element){
    return element.value == '' ? element.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc" : element.val()
}
```

Comment: try `(element.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc")`

Comment: Is the value `null` or an empty string?

Comment: Typo; vote to close.

Comment: @RossWilson: The `value` of an `input` (or `select`) is never `null`. And if there's no `value` (e.g., it's not a form field), `.value` will give `undefined`.

Comment: @Maxx don't work :/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry I misread the question.

Comment: @RossWilson empty string...

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique: I've updated the answer slightly, there's a shorter way to do it if you want...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have your assignment in the wrong place:

```
function emptyto(element){
    return element.style.backgroundColor = element.value == '' ? "#ccc" : element.val();
    // ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Separately: DOM elements don't have a `val` method. You either wanted to use `value` in both places:

```
function emptyto(element){
    return element.style.backgroundColor = element.value == '' ? "#ccc" : element.value;
    // ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery, to wrap the element and use `val` in both places (along with `css`):

```
function emptyto(element){
    var $el = $(element);
    return $el.css("backgroundColor", $el.val() == '' ? "#ccc" : $el.val());
}
```

---

Actually, since `''` is a *falsy* value, we can use the [*curiously-powerful `||` operator*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)<sup>1</sup> to simplify that:

```
function emptyto(element){
    return element.style.backgroundColor = element.value || "#ccc";
}
```

*<sup>1</sup> (That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*